# Karate - test 500 server response

Tags: karate

my question is how to test 500 server response?

Example: Application1 calls Application2.
If Application2 is down Application1 should return 500 with proper message.

How can I simulate that Application2 is down? Is there way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: yes use karate mocks: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-netty - also see other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+mock+dependent - and feel free to ask a specific question next time with what you have attempted